# Missmatch Error when running sql query on databricks

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to run a simple sql query on databricks and I am getting mismatch errors. I not sure how to resolve this

sample data

[image: sample data]

my code:

```
%sql
select UnitPrice, InvoiceDate
from tester2
where InvoiceDate = 2010-01-12
```

error

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(tester2.`InvoiceDate` = ((2010 - 
1) - 12))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(tester2.`InvoiceDate` = ((2010 - 1) 
- 12))' (date and int).; line 3 pos 6;
'Project ['UnitPrice, 'InvoiceDate]
```

Comment: Put the date in string quotation marks

Comment: @Umar.H, datatype is date but will try it and get back to you

Comment: 2019-19-07 will generate an error as it's not a valid data type it the engine will try to read it as an int until it hits the hyphen then it will error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datetime and date data types values should be quoted in single quotes :

```
select UnitPrice, InvoiceDate
from tester2
where InvoiceDate = '2010-01-12'
```